# How to use JPQL MEMBER OF operator with extra condition in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpql

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LETTERS")
public class Letter {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "ID")
 protected Long id;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "SENDER_ID")
 protected User sender;

 @ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(name = "LETTERS_RECIPIENTS", 
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LETTER_ID"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "RECIPIENT_ID"))
 protected final List<User> recipients;
 ……………………..
}
```

which maps into these database tables:

```
LETTERS
ID  SENDER_ID
3   5

LETTERS_RECIPIENTS
LETTER_ID   RECIPIENT_ID
3   6
3   7
```

I try to query the tables with the following JPQL queries:

```
 "SELECT new " + LetterInfo.class.getCanonicalName() + "(o) FROM " + Letter.class.getSimpleName() + " AS o WHERE o.sender = :user OR :user MEMBER OF o.recipients" 


 "SELECT new " + LetterInfo.class.getCanonicalName() + "(o) FROM " + Letter.class.getSimpleName() + " AS o JOIN o.recipients AS r WHERE o.sender = :user OR r = :user"

  Query q = em.createQuery(…);
  q.setParameter("user", p_user);
  List<LetterInfo> result = q.getResultList();
```

where **p_user.id = 5** 
and get **result.size() = 2** 
although when i use only `WHERE o.sender = :user` i get **result.size() = 1** and when
only `WHERE :user MEMBER OF o.recipients` i get **result.size() = 0** as expected.

**EDIT:** After enabling SQL logging, I discovered that EclipseLink translates the first query with MEMBER OF operator into this:

```
SELECT L.ID, L.SENDER_ID 
FROM LETTERS_RECIPIENTS LR, USERS U, LETTERS L 
WHERE (L.SENDER_ID = 5 OR 5 = U.ID) AND (LR.LETTER_ID = L.ID AND U.ID = LR.RECIPIENT_ID)
```

So it seems that the only solution is using DISTINCT keyword or is there a better solution?

Comment: Unclear. Which of the two queries are you executing, with which argument, and getting what as a result? Anyway, you're missing the distinct keyword: select distinct o from Letter o.

Comment: I'm executing both queries independently and get identical results. I know about DISTINCT but why result doubles? Rows in join table don't meet condition.

Comment: Turn SQL logging on, and you'll see which SQL query is being executed.